# How to find and replace min value in dataframe with text in r

Tags: r

i have dataframe with 20 columns and I like to identify the minimum value in each of the column and replace them with text such as "min". Appreciate any help

**sample data :**

```
   a    b     c
-0.05 0.31  0.62
 0.78 0.25 -0.01
 0.68 0.33 -0.04
-0.01 0.30  0.56
 0.55 0.28 -0.03
```

**Desired output**

```
    a    b     c
  min   0.31  0.62
  0.78  min  -0.01
  0.68  0.33   min
 -0.01  0.30  0.56
  0.55  0.28 -0.03
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `apply` a function to each column that replaces the minimum value with a string. This returns a `matrix` which could be converted into a data frame if desired. As IceCreamToucan pointed out, all rows will be of type `character` since each variable must have the same type:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) {
    x[x == min(x)] <- 'min'
    return(x)
})

     a       b      c      
[1,] "min"   "0.31" "0.62" 
[2,] "0.78"  "min"  "-0.01"
[3,] "0.68"  "0.33" "min"  
[4,] "-0.01" "0.3"  "0.56" 
[5,] "0.55"  "0.28" "-0.03"
```

Comment: It might be better to do `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, x == min(x), "min"))` to get a data frame in return.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method below, but know that this converts all your columns to character, since vectors must have elements which all have the same type.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(~ replace(.x, which.min(.x), 'min'))
#       a    b     c
# 1   min 0.31  0.62
# 2  0.78  min -0.01
# 3  0.68 0.33   min
# 4 -0.01  0.3  0.56
# 5  0.55 0.28 -0.03
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(df, MARGIN=2, FUN=(function(x){x[which.min(x)] <- 'min'; return(x)})
```